# Determining if the font color of an Excel shape is automatic or not

Tags: excel, vba

In the Excel macro I am trying to determine if the font color of a shape is "automatic".

As shown below, if the `ColorIndex` is `xlColorIndexAutomatic`, the font color is determined to be "automatic".

However, when I set the font color to black (color code: `0`) in the Excel color panel, the `ColorIndex` is set to `xlColorIndexAutomatic`, so I cannot distinguish between black and "automatic".

Please let me know if there is a way to distinguish them.

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes(0).TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic Then
  '//
End If
```

Comment: What precisely are you trying to achieve? In almost all circumstances, Automatic *will* be equivalent to black, unless the background is sufficiently dark, for which Automatic will be set to white.

Comment: If you really need to distinguish, set the `Color` (not the ColorIndex) to 1. This is almost black.

Comment: @FunThomas he is setting the color black *"in the Excel color panel"* as he writes. Not so easy there to choose the color that results in `Color = 1`. Therefore he would have to use a VBA code. • And I see no chance to distinguish which was chosen in the color panel. Either you choose "automatic" or "black" both results in the same values in VBA.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Yes, that's true, you can't easily set the color-Value 1 (or something similar) manually. The strange thing is if you set the font color of a cell to black, it get's the colorIndex 1 and you *can* distinguish - in opposite to a shape.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks guys!

I made the automatic decision to use the code below.

```
shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ClorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic And
shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Fill.ForceColor.ObjectForceColor = msoNotThemeColor
```

Comment: Your answer is unclear and with some typos, as `"ClorIndex"`, `"ForceColor"`,`"ObjectForceColor"`. So, the code is useless. Please review it or consider deleting it.